# CLion CMake Error: execution of make failed

Tags: clion

I'm getting the following error from CLion which means I can't compile anything. It was working fine until I updated my Mac's OS, which may or may not be related. I've tried reinstalling CLion and it did not work.

```
/Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/mac/bin/cmake - 
DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug "-DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=xcode-select --install" -G 
    "CodeBlocks - Unix Makefiles" /Users/emma/CLionProjects/untitled2
-- The C compiler identification is unknown
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
CMake Error: Generator: execution of make failed. Make command was: 
"/Users/emma/CLionProjects/untitled2/cmake-build-debug/xcode-select -- 
install" "cmTC_021a3/fast"
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- broken
CMake Error at 
/Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/mac/share/cmake- 
3.13/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:52 (message):
  The C compiler

    "/usr/bin/cc"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

    Change Dir: /Users/emma/CLionProjects/untitled2/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

    Run Build Command:"/Users/emma/CLionProjects/untitled2/cmake-build-debug/xcode-select --install" "cmTC_021a3/fast"
    No such file or directory
    Generator: execution of make failed. Make command was: 
"/Users/emma/CLionProjects/untitled2/cmake-build-debug/xcode-select --install" "cmTC_021a3/fast"




  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:2 (project)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/Users/emma/CLionProjects/untitled2/cmake-build- 
debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/Users/emma/CLionProjects/untitled2/cmake-build- 
debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".

[Failed to reload]
```